# Rolling window forecast using slide_tsibble

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `slide_tsibble()` function to do a rolling window forecast. I was able to obtain the forecast but when I piped it to the `accuracy()` function, I got an error message.

The dataset i used is the eth stock returns with 1478 observations. I am trying to obtain the 1-step forecast for a fixed window of 978 observations, and get its accuracy.

```
ethslide <- eth_ts %>% as_tsibble(index = trading_day) %>% 
slide_tsibble(.size = 978, .step = 1) 

fc <- ethslide %>% model(
  arima = ARIMA(diff_lg_eth ~ pdq(1,0,0))
) %>% forecast(h=1)

fc %>% accuracy(eth_ts)
```

the error i got is

> Error in stats::acf(.resid, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 2, na.action = na.action, : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example eg provide `eth_ts` as the output of dput(eth_ts) or a subset of this if its large so that other people have some data to try to help you. Also show all libraries you are using so we don't have to guess